# Gson JSON deserialization does not work for Enums

Tags: java, android, json, gson, deserialization

I have this enum

```
    public enum TornadoType {
    @SerializedName("RADAR INDICATED")
    RADAR_INDICATED("#ef8540", "RADAR INDICATED"),

    @SerializedName("OBSERVED")
    OBSERVED("#ff0000", "OBSERVED"),

    @SerializedName("POSSIBLE")
    POSSIBLE("#fdf151", "POSSIBLE");

    private final String color;

    @Getter
    private final String type;

    public int getColor() {
        return Color.parseColor(color);
    }

    TornadoType(String color, String name) {
        this.color = color;
        this.type = name;
    }
}
```

I am trying to deserialize a enum value like this

```
TornadoType tornadoType = new Gson().fromJson("RADAR INDICATED", TornadoType.class);
```

but I am consistently getting null value for `tornadoType`. I have also tried below

```
    java.lang.reflect.Type type = new TypeToken<TornadoType>() {
    }.getType();
    TornadoType tornadoType = new Gson().fromJson("RADAR INDICATED", type);
    return tornadoType.getColor();
```

which also doesn't seem to be working for me. I am using gson version 2.8 on Android. Every google search says `Enum` deserialisations are supported out of the box and this should just work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `RADAR INDICATED` doesn't look like valid JSON to me. How is such a value serialized?

Comment: @JohannesKuhn a string is perfectly valid json. `"RADAR INDICATED"` is valid JSON while `RADAR INDICATED` is not.

Comment: And you try to deserialize `RADAR INDICATED`, not `"RADAR INDICATED"`.

Comment: ah, I see what you mean let me try that

Comment: @JohannesKuhn yup it works now, thank you very much